# Node.js Express handle errors function

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

In express app, I researched that we can handle error using something like this:

```
// app.js
app.use(function (error, req, res, next) {
    // Handle errors
});
```

my questions are:

1. am I right that this function will be called **only** if there is an error? I could not get this function to call if there is no error. Am I missing anything?
2. is there any case that this function will get called even there is **no** error?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Middleware with arity of 4 (that is: `err, req, res, next`) are error handlers, and will be called when there's an error.

Errors may be uncaught exceptions in your other middleware, or explicitly errors that you raise when you call `next(err)` instead of `next()` with no arguments.

There will be cases when these handlers won't be called. For example: errors that happen in async blocks.

Comment: very useful info and quick reply. Appreciated @Nitzan Shaked. +1